# Disk space issue after apt-get update

Tags: apt, filesystem, files, root

I did a system update with `sudo apt-get update` and rebooted. After the reboot an error came up showing that i'm out of disk space. was barly able to access my desktop.
I checked the space util and noticed that there are 2 very large files (over 20GB) in the directory: `/var/lib/apt/list/partial/`

- za.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.bz2 (21.2 GB)
- security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.bz2 (21.2 GB)

I managed to delete them and rebooted the system and all was fine. Then I did an update again and the same issue occured again.

Is this a bug?

System info :
Ubuntu 15.04 - Daily updated

Answer (score 4):

If you look, for example for your first file [here](http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/dists/vivid-updates/main/binary-amd64/), you'll notice that the size of these files is barely 100KB, so you have something pesky going on—probably a network failure or something like that. Have you tried to check the content of these monster files? Is the filesystem clean?

Try to remove all the cached packages:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then repair the database:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Finally repeat the update and upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this bug that made my computer runs very slow. At first I thought it's because the new ppa I've just added. But then I discover that it's a bug that has been confirmed in the launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+source/apt/+bug/1445239

It turns out there's a problem in the `ServerState::HeaderLine()` where it parses

> Content-Range header:
>
> Content-Range: bytes 587-600/601

And in  `HttpServerState::RunData()` there's a code `In.Limit(Size - StartPos);` that returns a -1 hence infinite loop for the MaxGet.

Go check the thread for full info.

Launchpad user Anton Blanchard and the others have made a patch for the bug, but it's still in the dev distro of *Willy Werewolf* and waiting for the developers of *Vivid* to fix this problem.

For now I suggest to be careful when running the apt-get update and be standby to cancel it if the lists/partial folder gets to grown into the gigabytes size. Deleting the folder will temporarily fixed the problem for me.
Or you could schedule a cron jobs for it.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get update` updates the package manager with the latest versions of software - this is what the two .bz2 files are. It does not actually install new software.

You need to follow `sudo apt-get update` with `sudo apt-get upgrade`, which will install the latest versions of everything.

You can combine them into one command with

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: I've tried doing the "upgrade" afterwards, but i still get an error :  

Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

As soon as i run the update command the 2 files gets rebuild by apt-get.

Comment: How much disk space do you have? Please [edit] your question to include the output of `df -h`.

Comment: After  delete the 2 files i can run the :       sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade   -   command but it will not complete the upgrade due to the error