# Disk full after sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade

I ran into [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error) and did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. In the middle of the process my disk was full.

- [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629238/disk-space-issue-after-apt-get-update) I am suggested to `sudo apt-get clean`.
- I was also told somewhere in the process to run `'sudo dpkg --configure -a'` and this is also mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a).

Both options do not work because the disk is full. I know that there is a lot of disk space occupied in `var/cache` but I do not know which files to delete without causing even more damage.

I am obviously no expert on Ubuntu. What are my options?

EDIT:

Using `sudo apt clean` indeed reduced the usage of the disk from 100% (55G) to 98% according to `df -h`:

```
Dateisystem                 Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev                          63G       0   63G    0% /dev
tmpfs                         13G     26M   13G    1% /run
/dev/mapper/XXXXXX--vg-root   55G     51G  1,4G   98% /
tmpfs                         63G    396M   63G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5,0M    4,0K  5,0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         63G       0   63G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2               237M    156M   69M   70% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1               511M    3,3M  508M    1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/XXXXXX--vg-home  404G    211G  173G   55% /home
/dev/sda1                    3,6T     21G  3,4T    1% /data
tmpfs                         13G     56K   13G    1% /run/user/1000
```

Calling 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' gives this long output with German flavour:

```
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-command-line-tools-11-3:
 cuda-command-line-tools-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-cupti-dev-11-3 (>= 11.3.111); aber:
  Version von cuda-cupti-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-command-line-tools-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-gdb-11-3 (>= 11.3.109); aber:
  Version von cuda-gdb-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-command-line-tools-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-nvprof-11-3 (>= 11.3.111); aber:
  Version von cuda-nvprof-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-command-line-tools-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-nvtx-11-3 (>= 11.3.109); aber:
  Version von cuda-nvtx-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-command-line-tools-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-sanitizer-11-3 (>= 11.3.111); aber:
  Version von cuda-sanitizer-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-command-line-tools-11-3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
initramfs-tools (0.133+deb10u1) wird eingerichtet ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-nsight-compute-11-3:
 cuda-nsight-compute-11-3 hängt ab von nsight-compute-2021.1.1 (>= 2021.1.1.5); aber:
  Paket nsight-compute-2021.1.1 ist nicht installiert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-nsight-compute-11-3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-libraries-11-3:
 cuda-libraries-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-cudart-11-3 (>= 11.3.109); aber:
  Version von cuda-cudart-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-nvrtc-11-3 (>= 11.3.109); aber:
  Version von cuda-nvrtc-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-11-3 hängt ab von libcublas-11-3 (>= 11.5.1.109); aber:
  Version von libcublas-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.4.2.10064-1.
 cuda-libraries-11-3 hängt ab von libcufft-11-3 (>= 10.4.2.109); aber:
  Version von libcufft-11-3 auf dem System ist 10.4.2.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-11-3 hängt ab von libcurand-11-3 (>= 10.2.4.109); aber:
  Version von libcurand-11-3 auf dem System ist 10.2.4.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-11-3 hängt ab von libcusolver-11-3 (>= 11.1.2.109); aber:
  Version von libcusolver-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.1.1.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-11-3 hängt ab von libcusparse-11-3 (>= 11.6.0.109); aber:
  Version von libcusparse-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.5.0.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-11-3 hängt ab von libnpp-11-3 (>= 11.3.3.95); aber:
  Version von libnpp-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.3.44-1.
 cuda-libraries-11-3 hängt ab von libnvjpeg-11-3 (>= 11.5.0.109); aber:
  Version von libnvjpeg-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.4.1.58-1.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-libraries-11-3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-compiler-11-3:
 cuda-compiler-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-nvcc-11-3 (>= 11.3.109); aber:
  Version von cuda-nvcc-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-compiler-11-3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-toolkit-11-3:
 cuda-toolkit-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-compiler-11-3 (>= 11.3.1); aber:
  Paket cuda-compiler-11-3 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
 cuda-toolkit-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-libraries-11-3 (>= 11.3.1); aber:
  Paket cuda-libraries-11-3 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-toolkit-11-3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-libraries-dev-11-3:
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-cudart-dev-11-3 (>= 11.3.109); aber:
  Version von cuda-cudart-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-thrust-11-3 (>= 11.3.109); aber:
  Version von cuda-thrust-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-driver-dev-11-3 (>= 11.3.109); aber:
  Version von cuda-driver-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-3 (>= 11.3.109); aber:
  Version von cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von libcublas-dev-11-3 (>= 11.5.1.109); aber:
  Version von libcublas-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.4.2.10064-1.
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von libcufft-dev-11-3 (>= 10.4.2.109); aber:
  Version von libcufft-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 10.4.2.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von libcurand-dev-11-3 (>= 10.2.4.109); aber:
  Version von libcurand-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 10.2.4.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von libcusolver-dev-11-3 (>= 11.1.2.109); aber:
  Version von libcusolver-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.1.1.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von libcusparse-dev-11-3 (>= 11.6.0.109); aber:
  Version von libcusparse-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.5.0.58-1.
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von libnpp-dev-11-3 (>= 11.3.3.95); aber:
  Version von libnpp-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.3.44-1.
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 hängt ab von libnvjpeg-dev-11-3 (>= 11.5.0.109); aber:
  Version von libnvjpeg-dev-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.4.1.58-1.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
nvidia-kernel-dkms (470.82.01-1) wird eingerichtet ...
Removing old nvidia-current-470.82.01 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 470.82.01
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-current-470.82.01 DKMS files...
Building for 4.19.0-18-amd64
Building initial module for 4.19.0-18-amd64
Done.

nvidia-current.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-18-amd64/updates/dkms/

nvidia-current-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-18-amd64/updates/dkms/

nvidia-current-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-18-amd64/updates/dkms/

nvidia-current-peermem.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-18-amd64/updates/dkms/

nvidia-current-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-18-amd64/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-11-4:
 cuda-11-4 hängt ab von cuda-demo-suite-11-4 (>= 11.4.100); aber:
  Paket cuda-demo-suite-11-4 ist nicht installiert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-11-4 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-tools-11-3:
 cuda-tools-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-command-line-tools-11-3 (>= 11.3.1); aber:
  Paket cuda-command-line-tools-11-3 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-tools-11-3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-visual-tools-11-3:
 cuda-visual-tools-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-nsight-compute-11-3 (>= 11.3.1); aber:
  Paket cuda-nsight-compute-11-3 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
 cuda-visual-tools-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 (>= 11.3.1); aber:
  Paket cuda-libraries-dev-11-3 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
 cuda-visual-tools-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-nsight-11-3 (>= 11.3.109); aber:
  Version von cuda-nsight-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.
 cuda-visual-tools-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-nvvp-11-3 (>= 11.3.111); aber:
  Version von cuda-nvvp-11-3 auf dem System ist 11.3.58-1.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-visual-tools-11-3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-runtime-11-3:
 cuda-runtime-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-libraries-11-3 (>= 11.3.1); aber:
  Paket cuda-libraries-11-3 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-runtime-11-3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
nvidia-driver (470.82.01-1) wird eingerichtet ...
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda:
 cuda hängt ab von cuda-11-4 (>= 11.4.3); aber:
  Paket cuda-11-4 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von cuda-11-3:
 cuda-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-runtime-11-3 (>= 11.3.1); aber:
  Paket cuda-runtime-11-3 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
 cuda-11-3 hängt ab von cuda-toolkit-11-3 (>= 11.3.1); aber:
  Paket cuda-toolkit-11-3 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes cuda-11-3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
cuda-drivers-470 (470.82.01-1) wird eingerichtet ...
cuda-drivers (470.82.01-1) wird eingerichtet ...
cuda-runtime-11-4 (11.4.3-1) wird eingerichtet ...
Trigger für initramfs-tools (0.133+deb10u1) werden verarbeitet ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-18-amd64
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 cuda-command-line-tools-11-3
 cuda-nsight-compute-11-3
 cuda-libraries-11-3
 cuda-compiler-11-3
 cuda-toolkit-11-3
 cuda-libraries-dev-11-3
 cuda-11-4
 cuda-tools-11-3
 cuda-visual-tools-11-3
 cuda-runtime-11-3
 cuda
 cuda-11-3
```

Comment: The `sudo apt clean` command *should* give you some breathing space to complete the installation, as that will remove cached installation packages. How large is your Ubuntu disk? Is there a message to say *where* you need space? Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `df -h`, which will show where your space is being consumed and how much is allocated? 

Comment: Thank you that helped. There is an issue with cuda but I have no idea how to proceed. I want to reverse the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` call.

Comment: We need to see **all** the errors you're seeing.  You then need to start identifying what on your system is eating the most resources, because it sounds like you have too much stuff on your disk.

Comment: Thank you, I made a second edit.

Comment: Your system is messed up! Although this is fixable, you need to put a lot of effort and time to solve this, so, I'd recommend reinstalling ubuntu. It's the best option! Note:- If you want to reply to a user, please ping them. You can ping them using '@' in front of their user name. eg:- @ThomasWard

Comment: Also, you can run:- `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt --fix-broken install` to fix this. If you want to free up `/var/cache` then you could run `sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` to remove obsoleted packages. After that, try all the clean and dpkg commands again.

Comment: That's quite a healthy `/data` partition. I wonder if you could move some files from your root to that location (at least temporarily) to resolve the issues. How large is your `/var/log` directory? I have seen some log directories consume gigabytes of space when things start to go sideways 